# Flutter immutables: rebuilding immutable collection using `freezed` + `kt_dart`

Tags: flutter, dart, model, immutability, provider

I have a couple of `freezed` models:

```dart
@freezed
abstract class User with _$User {
  factory User({
    @required KtMap<int, House> houses,
  }) = _User;
}

@freezed
abstract class House with _$House {
  factory House({
    @required KtSet<Room> rooms,
  }) = _House;
}

enum Room { bedroom, kitchen, toilet, hall, boxroom }
```

I also have a collection

```dart
  KtMap<int, User> _users = mapFrom({
    1: User(
      houses: mapFrom({
        1: House(
          rooms: setFrom(
            Room.values.toSet(),
          ),
        )
      }),
    ),
  });

  KtMap<int, User> get users => _users.toMap();
```

My goal is to remove 1 room from the inner map and return the updated collection. How can I do it properly?
Here is my try (not working):

```dart
  void removeRoom(int userId, int houseId, Room room) {
    _users[userId].copyWith().houses[houseId].rooms.toMutableSet()..remove(room);

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Don't advise me `built_value`, I don't wanna use it due to ugly syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I took me a whole lot of time, but I found the solution:

[image: solution]